# Freezing at installing ubuntu : looping gdm starting sessions

Tags: system-installation, gdm

I hope I'm duplicating previous questions (I've searched with "ubuntu installer multiple gdm sessions loop freeze", read through this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/111298#111298) , but I think my problem is a bit different) : I'm stuck at installing Ubuntu (both with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Ubuntu 19.10 USB Live installers).

When launching the LTS live usb key, it ends with a gdm session starting multiple times and freezing (with sessions from c143 to sometimes sessions c189). The graphics card is a Nvidia MX 230 : shouldn't I try to use the nomodeset option? When launching with the normal desktop 19.10 version, I only have a prompt from Grub.

Comment: I've gone through this problem (partially), as the Desktop Live USB did work ... once out of two times, nearly! So I could install Ubuntu 19.10, then ... cope with the laptop starting once out of three times I think, lots of red errors in dmesg, but I'm keeping working with them (after bad -too short- password and wrong keyboard layout at registering user time).
If anybody knows for the looping gdm sessions starting (I think that's not the first time I see this), I'm keen on learning from that.

Comment: Also, I didn't figured out if I am to answer my own question or delete it (I've tried [RESOLV*] in the title but have been discouraged by  the site), so please feel free to indicate the right manner. Thx